# Numbers in the series: The British way

Tags: lateral-thinking, number-sequence

What are the next two numbers in series?

> Six hundred and forty
>
> Five thousand
>
> Eight thousand
>
> ?
>
> ?
>
> What are the next two numbers?  Is this a trick question?

Note: I am using the UK way of numbering that includes "and". Unlike us Americans who write many different ways :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

So it looks like

> Each number you've written contains each vowel exactly once.

Which means the next two numbers are (I think)

> Nine thousand
>  Twenty-six thousand

Answer (score 6):

I think number in sequence is :

> 9000, 80,000 ( Nine Thousand , Eighty Thousand)

Reasoning :

> I observed in above sequence all numbers contains every vowels ("a,e,i,o,u") only onces all other number after 9000 contains fews vowels or repeated vowels if we check  .
> Nine Thousand is made up of (a,e,i,o,u) ,same for Eighty Thousand .

Comment: 26000?  What about that number?

Comment: I miss that number i thought all number will begin with 6,5,8 .. so on . but ,i was wrong maybe