# Numbers with vowels used twice

Tags: no-computers, number-property

This question is linked to [Numbers in series](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/96566/numbers-in-the-series-the-british-way)

If you write out the numbers the British way (using "and")

> What is the smallest number that has *all* the vowels used exactly
>   **twice**.
>
> What is the largest 6 digit number that has the same property?

Bonus Question

> How high you have to go to find for a number with all vowels used
>   exactly 3 times? ( "and" can be used only once). Is there such a
>   number?

Comment: Maybe a no-computer tag should be added?

Comment: I feel I should clarify this before I actually answered, but as a non-native, is 1101 written as `one thousand and one hundred and one` (two `and`s)? Or just one `and` and one comma?

Comment: Or, is there some official reference for the British way of writing numbers?

Comment: Nothing official @newbie but here is one ref https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_numerals

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe the answer is,

> 4085 (**four thousand and eighty-five**)
>  962000 (**nine hundred and sixty-two thousand**)

My approach

> First I made a table of all words and vowel appearences.
>  
>  `[word]       aeiou
>  a            10000
>  one          01010
>  ... full table can be found at https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/X8sfQnhVFK/`

First question,

> From the table it's pretty clear no number <100 could work. We show why numbers in 100~999 couldn't work.
>  Those numbers have format: `[] hundred (and []-[]/[])` (here [] stands for a word)
>  
>  `hundred      01001
>  and          10000
>  [need]       11221`
>
>  We need 7 vowels, however one word (except the -teen case, where 2 words can be used then) contains no more than 2 vowels and we only have 3 slots.
>  Now 4 digit numbers. Plain `[] thousand` certainly won't work. Notice that `thousand` and `and` both contain `a`, so we can at most have one `and`.
>  Two cases left: `[] thousand and [] hundred` and `[] thousand and []-[]/[]`.
>  First case:
>  
>  `hundred      01001
>  thousand     10011
>  and          10000
>  [need]       01210`
>
>  Looking through all digits, sadly there aren't two digits matching this need.
>  Second case looks more promising.
>  
>  `thousand     10011
>  and          10000
>  [need]       02211`
>
>  As before, we need two or three words here with 6 vowels in total. Our only bet is to have three words, all with 2 vowels.
>  The only -ty's with 2 vowels:
>  
>  `seventy      02000
>  eighty       01100
>  ninety       01100`
>
>  If we choose `seventy`, we're left with `00211` and sadly no match again. If we choose `eighty` instead, we're left with `01111`. `four` and `five` is such a match.

Second question,

> 6 digits, so a few hundred thousands. `[] hundred thousand` won't work. As said, we can only have at most one `and` pairing with `thousand`. Three cases: `[] hundred and [] thousand`, `[] hundred thousand and [] hundred`, `[] hundred and []-[]/[] thousand` (There's also `[] hundred thousand and []-[]/[]` but is certainly smaller).
>  The second case has 3`u`s so not valid and the first case is identical to the `[] thousand and [] hundred` discussed in the first question. The only bet is the third case.
>  
>  `hundred      01001
>  thousand     10011
>  and          10000
>  [need]       01210`
>
>  Two digits won't work. -teen's have two `e`s. So we're going for the three word case.
>  To make the number as big as possible, we put the largest digit `nine` in the front.
>  
>  `nine         01100
>  [need]       00110`
>
>  Two vowels left. Again we choose the biggest possible number to put with one vowel, which is `sixty`. We're left with the one last `o` so the last digit is `two`.

On the bonus question,

> The answer is **yes**. For example, 3000000000084000 (**three quadrillion and eighty-four thousand**). I'm not sure if it's the smallest one (hopefully not).

Comment: Are you sure about your second answer @newbie?

Comment: Umm I've commented under the question, can you check that? @DEEM

Comment: I think I'm pretty sure about the second answer.

Comment: Very nice analysis.  The computer search would still be useful but also incomplete without it.